# How to handle object references in JSON document with Newtonsoft Json.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a json dataset that comes with standard data fields and reference fields. It looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Book",
        "description":"Something you can read"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"newspaper",
        "description": {
            "ref":"0.description"
        }
    }
]
```

This is my data model:

```
public class PhysicalObject {
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default)]
    public int id;

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default)]
    public string name;

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("description", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default)]  // FIXED should have been description not desc
    public string desc;
}
```

Every property in the json file has a specific type such as `int` for `id`, and `string` for `description` however every property can also link to another via a `ref`. In this case, the `description` of `id`= 2 is the same as `id` = 1

Is there a way via Error handling or creating some kind of fallback deserialization that can be applied that can allow me to serialize the `ref`?

Note that because of other requirements, I must use the Newtonsoft Json.NET library to resolve this. Information about other libraries or techniques to solve this are informative but probably won't resolve the issue.

Comment: What is your desired data model to which you are trying to deserialize?  If you just declare `description` to be an `object` then Json.NET will deserialize it to something -- either a `string` or a `JObject` as appropriate.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the reply. I added the data model to the original post. I know I could deserialize it using `DeserializeAnonymousType` and get the data into a generic object. However, I wanted to feed it right into the specifically typed objects. Making description into a generic object would help if it were only one... however, this is a super simplistic example and I have up to 30 fields per object and many levels where all of those fields can either be a specific type or reference.

Comment: In the end, I want both objects to have the same string but they don't have to both point to the same string in memory. As long as object1.description and object2.description are strings that contain "Something you can read" everything would be perfect.

Comment: Is `"1.description"` supposed to be a [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) reference to the preceding description?  If so then it should be `"0.description"` since the preceding item is the first item in the (zero-index-based) JSON array.  Perhaps `"1.description"` just comes from how you edited & simplified the question?

Comment: Sorry yes that is correct. It's just a simplified sample. I have edited it for clarity

Comment: Ah, but unfortunately I made a mistake also -- `"0.description"` isn't a valid JSONPath expression, it should be `"[0].description"`.  You'll have to write your own parsing code for the path.

Comment: Well if you don't actually need to preserve references and are OK with cloning the referenced values, you can do something quick-and-dirtyish like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ln7A3j.  But this seems to be converging on Avish's answer so I'm not sure there's a need to add another.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to turn that fiddle into an answer.

Comment: @dbc sorry for the delay, I was trying to find time to implement your solution. If you could answer with this I will select it. I was able to make your fiddle conform to the much more complex real situation than this sample. (Which includes different types of references and arrays of references, etc) Ultimately, this solution is best for me because of flexibility.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the scenario. The IDs are not used in the references? i.e. the `"0."` at the start of the reference string refers to an array index, not the `id` of some other object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preload your JSON into a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy, then use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to replace objects of the form `{"ref":"some.period-separated.path"}` with the tokens indicated in the path.  Then subsequently the `JToken` hierarchy can be deserialized to your final model.

The following extension method does the trick:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    const string refPropertyName = "ref";

    public static void ResolveRefererences(JToken root)
    {
        if (!(root is JContainer container))
            return;
        var refs = container.Descendants().OfType<JObject>().Where(o => IsRefObject(o)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(refs));
        foreach (var refObj in refs)
        {
            var path = GetRefObjectValue(refObj);
            var original = ResolveRef(root, path);
            if (original != null)
                refObj.Replace(original);
        }
    }

    static bool IsRefObject(JObject obj)
    {
        return GetRefObjectValue(obj) != null;
    }

    static string GetRefObjectValue(JObject obj)
    {
        if (obj.Count == 1)
        {
            var refValue = obj[refPropertyName];
            if (refValue != null && refValue.Type == JTokenType.String)
            {
                return (string)refValue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static JToken ResolveRef(JToken token, string path)
    {
        // TODO: determine whether it is possible for a property name to contain a '.' character, and if so, how the path will look.
        var components = path.Split('.'); 

        foreach (var component in components)
        {
            if (token is JObject obj)
                token = obj[component];
            else if (token is JArray array)
                token = token[int.Parse(component, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)];
            else
                // Or maybe just return null?
                throw new JsonException("Unexpected token type.");
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Then you would use it as follows:

```
// Load into intermediate JToken hierarchy; do not perform DateTime recognition yet.
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });

// Replace {"ref": "...") objects with their references.
JsonExtensions.ResolveRefererences(root);

// Deserialize directly to final model.  DateTime recognition should get performed now.
var list = root.ToObject<List<PhysicalObject>>();
```

Notes:

1. This solution does not attempt to preserve references, i.e. to make the deserialized `{"ref":"some.period-separated.path"}` refer to the same instance as the deserialized original.  While Json.NET does have functionality to [preserve object references](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) via `"$ref"` and `"$id"` properties, it has several limitations including:

   - It does not handle references to primitives, only objects and arrays.
   - It does not allow for forward-references, only backward references. It's not clear from the question whether the `"ref"` properties in your JSON might refer to values later in the document.

   These limitations would complicate transforming the reference syntax shown in the question into Json.NET's syntax.
2. It's a good idea to defer [`DateTime` recognition](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) until final deserialization.  If your model has `string` properties whose JSON values might happen to look like ISO 8601 dates then premature date recognition may cause the string values to get modified.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ln7A3j).

Comment: Your use of LINQ to JSON to find the ref objects is much better than the recursive approach in my answer. But note that your resolution logic tries to resolve reference paths against the root document, whereas the OP's scenario has reference paths where the first element is the `$id` of some other object in the document, which is a different use case.

Comment: Reading the other comments I see I might have misunderstood the original requirement, so the OP will have to clarify. Other than that, our answers are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: I apologize if my question was a bit more vague. What I wanted was the ability to parse out the reference and build it rather than using a canned system as my reference variables are very complicated (references are sometimes ids, sometimes elements, sometimes mixtures). Although both answers are completely valid, I went with this one because it gave me the fine control over the references I needed. I did have to add substantial code beyond this, but this worked as a great boiler plate.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need some mechanism that resolves those references.

Here are two approaches:

### 1. Using built-in reference handling

One such mechanism is the Newtonsoft serializer's [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) property, which does exactly what you describe, except it looks for `$id` and `$ref` instead of `id` and `ref`.

To use this, you could transform the JSON tree before it's being converted into typed objects, by first reading it into a JSON tree representation (using [`JToken.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonAny.htm)), then traversing this tree, replacing `id` and `ref` properties with `$id` and `$ref` (since the intermediate JSON tree is modifiable and dynamic in nature, you can do this easily).

Then you could convert this transformed tree into your typed objects using the built-in reference resolution mechanism, by using [`JObject.CreateReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateReader.htm) to obtain a `JsonReader` over the transformed tree, which you can give to [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize.htm) to instruct it to deserialize it into your desired type.

```
T DeserializeJsonWithReferences<T>(string input) 
{
  var jsonTree = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
  TransformJsonTree(jsonTree);  // renames `id` and `ref` properties in-place
  var jsonReader = jsonTree.CreateReader();
  var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer() { 
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferenceHandling.All 
  };
  var deserialized = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
  return deserialized;
}

void TransformJsonTree(JToken token)
{
  var container = token as JContainer;
  if (container == null) 
    return;

  foreach (propName in SpecialPropertyNames)  // {"id", "ref"}
  {
    objects = container
      .Descendants()
      .OfType<JObject>()
      .Where(x => x.ContainsKey(propName));

    foreach (obj in objects) 
    {
      obj["$" + propName] = obj[propName];
      obj.Remove(propName);
    }
  }
}
```

---

### 2. Rolling your own reference resolution layer

A more complex approach, if you want to do it yourself: you'll need to add your own reference resolution layer, which would transform the JSON tree before it's converted into typed objects.

Here again, you can start by reading the JSON stream into a JSON tree representation. Then then you'll need to traverse that tree twice:

- On the first traversal you'll look for objects with an `id` property, and record them in a dictionary (from `id` to the object containing it).
- On the second traversal you'll look for objects with a `ref` property, and replace those ref-objects with the appropriate value, by looking up the referenced object by its `id` in the dictionary you created earlier, then navigating its properties according to the property chain described in the `ref` value. For example, if the ref is `3.address.city`, you'll look up the object with ID 3, then find the value of its `address` property, and then the value of the `city` property of that value, and that would be the final value of the reference.

Once the JSON tree has been transformed and all reference-objects have been replaced by their corresponding referenced values, you can convert the JSON tree into a typed object.

Code-wise that would be exactly the same as the previous example, except in `transformJsonTree`, instead of just renaming the `id` and `ref` properties, you'll have to implement the actual lookup and reference resolution logic.

It could look something like this:

```
IDictionary<string, JToken> BuildIdMap(JContainer container)
{
  return container
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Where(obj => obj.ContainsKey(IdPropertyName)
    .ToDictionary(obj => obj[IdPropertyName], obj => obj);
}

JToken LookupReferenceValue(string referenceString, IDictionary<string, JObject> idToObjectMap)
{
  var elements = referenceString.Split('.');
  var obj = idToObjectMap(elements[0]);

  for (int i = 1; i < elements.Length; i++) 
  {
    var elem = elements[i];
    switch (obj) 
    {
      case JArray jarr:
        obj = arr[elem];  // elem is a property name
        break;
      case JObject jobj:
        obj = jobj[int.Parse(elem)];  // elem is an array index
        break;
      default:
        throw Exception("You should throw a meaningful exception here"); 
    }
  }
}

void ResolveReferences(JContainer container, IDictionary<string, JObject> idToObjectMap)
{
  refObjects = container
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Where(obj.Count == 1 && obj => obj.ContainsKey(RefPropertyName))

  foreach (var refObject in refObjects) 
  {
    referenceString = refObject[RefPropertyName];
    referencedValue = LookupReferenceValue(refObject, idToObjectMap)
    refObject.Replace(referencedValue);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also take a look at [`JToken.SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) which allows you to navigate a property chain from a string or `JsonPath`, saving a lot of trouble from the above (assuming the reference syntax in your document matches the one Newtonsoft supports, e.g. with respect to array indices).

```
JToken LookupReferenceValue(string referenceString, IDictionary<string, JObject> idToObjectMap)
{
  var parts = referenceString.Split('.', 1); // only split on first '.'
  var id = parts[0];
  var tokenPath = parts[1];
  var referencedObject = idToObjectMap[id];
  var referencedValue = referencedObject.SelectToken(tokenPath);
  return referencedValue;
}
```

It's been years since I wrote any C# so please excuse any syntax errors or non-idiomatic usage. But that's the general idea.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, though a little more painful than I hoped it would be. Quick question for clarity: `transformedJsonTree` is actually `jsonTree` correct? Just a pseudocode?

Comment: A couple points about Json.NET's `PreserveReferencesHandling` functionality: 1) It does not handle references to primitives, only objects and arrays.  2) It does not allow for forward-references, only backward references.  It's not clear from the question whether the `"ref"` properties in OP's JSON might refer to values later in the document.  If they do then transforming to a `"$ref"` won't work, you need to reorder the values and make the `"$id"` object come first.

Comment: @KivakWolf yeah, I wrote this in the SO editor so expect errors and omissions. The general idea is described in the text; the code is just to illustrate what something like this would look like.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I didn't know that. In that case the home-rolled approach might make more sense.